# Suggestion bar still causing Kernel crashes?

Tags: crash, predictive-interface

On Mathematica 12.1.1, Windows 10.

When Suggestions bar is active, entering and evaluating the following crashes the Kernel.

```
zz = {{{0, 2}, {1, 1}, 28, 3}, {{1, 1}, {3, 1}, 56, 1}, {{1, 2}, {3, 1, 1}, 168, 0}}
```

Seeking confirmation before tagging as bug and reporting to WRI.

Comment: Yup, same here.

Comment: 1+,yes, same here.

Comment: Same on 12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019).

Comment: I have 12.2 and 11.3 on MacOS 10.13.6.  Neither of these crashes.  Suggestion bar message on both is: "Assuming a ragged array. | Use as *a list of lists* instead".